# Draw arrow on top left of scrollpane

Tags: java, swing, jscrollpane, java-2d

I have a JPanel within a JScrollPane. In my program, the JPanel shows an image of  map and it shows the current location of a vehicle. My program receives the location and current direction of the vehicle. I need to show this on the map.

I'm having a problem showing the direction of the vehicle. I want to show an arrow on the top left of the map's visible area to show the direction. The following is the code that I have tried. But it throws an exception when I scroll down.

```
Exception in thread "AWT-EventQueue-0" java.awt.image.RasterFormatException: Transformed height (-287) is less than or equal to 0.
    at java.awt.image.AffineTransformOp.createCompatibleDestImage(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.image.AffineTransformOp.filter(Unknown Source)
    at Test.paintComponent(Test.java:62)
    at javax.swing.JComponent.paint(Unknown Source)
    at javax.swing.JComponent.paintToOffscreen(Unknown Source)


import java.awt.BorderLayout;
import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.Dimension;
import java.awt.Graphics;
import java.awt.Graphics2D;
import java.awt.Rectangle;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
import java.awt.geom.AffineTransform;
import java.awt.image.AffineTransformOp;
import java.awt.image.BufferedImage;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.net.URL;
import java.util.Random;

import javax.imageio.ImageIO;
import javax.swing.BorderFactory;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.JScrollPane;
import javax.swing.Timer;

public class Test extends JPanel implements ActionListener {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        JFrame f = new JFrame();
        f.setSize(300, 400);
        Test view = new Test();
        Dimension minimumSize = new Dimension(1000, 1000);

        view.setBorder(BorderFactory.createLineBorder(Color.BLUE));
        JScrollPane comp = new JScrollPane(view);
        comp.setBorder(BorderFactory.createLineBorder(Color.RED));
        f.getContentPane().add(comp, BorderLayout.CENTER);
        f.setVisible(true);
        view.setPreferredSize(minimumSize);
    }

    private BufferedImage i;
    private Random r = new Random();

    public Test() {
        try {
            i = ImageIO
                    .read(new URL("https://cdn4.iconfinder.com/data/icons/cc_mono_icon_set/blacks/48x48/br_next.png"));
            new Timer(1000, this).start();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            throw new RuntimeException(e);
        }
    }

    @Override
    protected void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
        super.paintComponent(g);

        Graphics2D g2d = (Graphics2D) g.create();
        AffineTransform transform = g2d.getTransform();

        transform.rotate(r.nextFloat() * Math.PI * 2, i.getWidth() / 2, i.getHeight() / 2);
        AffineTransformOp op = new AffineTransformOp(transform, AffineTransformOp.TYPE_BILINEAR);

        Rectangle cb = g.getClipBounds();
        g2d.drawImage(op.filter(i, null), (int) cb.getX(), (int) cb.getY(), null);
    }

    @Override
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
        repaint();
    }

}
```

How can I make the arrow always visible on the top left corner even when the user scrolls using the scroll-bars?

Comment: The `JScrollPane` and the `JViewPort` are highly optimized.  When painted, you component's clip bounds will only include those areas which have changed and need to be refreshed by the viewport

Comment: @MadProgrammer using what way do you think I can achieve this?

Comment: Create your own custom `JViewPort` and paint the arrow over the top of the contents

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `JScrollPane` and `JViewport` are both highly optimised, when painted, the clipping bounds is only set to the area that actually needs to be updated (the area which was introduced)

A better idea might be to create your own `JViewport` onto which you can paint over the viewport's content

[image: Viewport]

```
import java.awt.BorderLayout;
import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.Dimension;
import java.awt.EventQueue;
import java.awt.Graphics;
import java.awt.Graphics2D;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
import java.awt.geom.AffineTransform;
import java.awt.image.BufferedImage;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.net.URL;
import java.util.Random;
import javax.imageio.ImageIO;
import javax.swing.BorderFactory;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.JScrollPane;
import javax.swing.JViewport;
import javax.swing.Timer;
import javax.swing.UIManager;
import javax.swing.UnsupportedLookAndFeelException;
import javax.swing.event.ChangeEvent;
import javax.swing.event.ChangeListener;

public class Test extends JPanel {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                try {
                    UIManager.setLookAndFeel(UIManager.getSystemLookAndFeelClassName());
                } catch (ClassNotFoundException | InstantiationException | IllegalAccessException | UnsupportedLookAndFeelException ex) {
                    ex.printStackTrace();
                }

                JFrame f = new JFrame();
                f.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
                f.setSize(300, 400);
                Test view = new Test();

                view.setBorder(BorderFactory.createLineBorder(Color.BLUE));
                JScrollPane comp = new JScrollPane();
                ViewPortDirection vp = new ViewPortDirection();
                comp.setViewport(vp);
                comp.setViewportView(view);
                comp.setBorder(BorderFactory.createLineBorder(Color.RED));
                f.getContentPane().add(comp, BorderLayout.CENTER);
                f.setVisible(true);
            }
        });
    }

    public static class ViewPortDirection extends JViewport {

        private BufferedImage i;
        private Random r = new Random();

        public ViewPortDirection() {
            try {
                i = ImageIO.read(new URL("https://cdn4.iconfinder.com/data/icons/cc_mono_icon_set/blacks/48x48/br_next.png"));
                new Timer(1000, new ActionListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                        repaint();
                    }
                }).start();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                throw new RuntimeException(e);
            }

            addChangeListener(new ChangeListener() {
                @Override
                public void stateChanged(ChangeEvent e) {
                    repaint(0, 0, i.getWidth(), i.getHeight());
                }
            });
        }

        @Override
        public void paint(Graphics g) {
            super.paint(g);

            Graphics2D g2d = (Graphics2D) g.create();
            AffineTransform transform = AffineTransform.getRotateInstance(r.nextFloat() * Math.PI * 2, i.getWidth() / 2, i.getHeight() / 2);

            int x = 0;
            int y = 0;
            g2d.setTransform(transform);
            g2d.drawImage(i, x, y, this);
            g2d.dispose();
        }

    }

    public Test() {
        setBackground(Color.BLUE);
    }

    @Override
    public Dimension getPreferredSize() {
        return new Dimension(1000, 1000);
    }

}
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Can you tell me why you over-rode `paint` method instead of `paintComponent`? And why you added `this` as the image observer?

Comment: 1- This is one if those rare occasions where you have to override paint, why? Because the JViewport actually has a child component which gets painted in a special way, overriding paintComponent would have painted the arrow under the view; 2- Why not? You should always pass "this" (where "this" is an instance of JComponent) to drawImage as it allows the component to respond to changes the image might trigger. Sure, in this instance you know it's a BufferedImage, but you can't guarantee that ;)